# Babel CLI --out-dir runs into permissions errors on second compile

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, babeljs

I'm running into a strange error that seems to be giving me permissions issues on Windows 10. I'm using the Babel CLI to compile some ES6 code, which works great using --out-file, which will overwrite files just fine, by --out-dir doesn't. Here's the relevant parts of my package.json:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-minify": "^0.2.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build-components": "babel Scripts/Components --out-file Scripts/Compiled/components.js",
        "build-pages": "babel Scripts/Pages --out-dir Scripts/Compiled/Pages",
        "watch-components": "babel Scripts/Components -w --out-file Scripts/Compiled/components.js",
        "watch-pages": "babel Scripts/Pages -w --out-dir Scripts/Compiled/Pages",
        "build-js": "npm run build-components && npm run build-pages"
    }
}
```

I'm building this within Visual Studio and using the [Task Runner Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TaskRunnerExplorer) package to run my commands (though it still fails from PowerShell, or running it as a build command within the project). The plugin runs '**npm run build-js**' on build and '**npm run watch-components**' and '**npm run watch-pages**' afterwards to watch for any changes. '**npm run watch-pages**' fails every time, as does '**npm run build-pages**' if the files it outputs to already exist. The only solution I've found so far is to delete the '**Scripts/Compiled/Pages**' folder every time I make a change to a file within '**Scripts/Pages**', which defeats the purpose of the watch command and is generally just annoying to have to do every time, especially when I'm doing a lot of file changes. Both build commands for the components works every time and will overwrite the old file without issue.

```
> babel Scripts/Pages --out-dir Scripts/Compiled/Pages
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\Scripts\Compiled\Pages\Index.Vue.js'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
at fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1224:33)
at outputFileSync (D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\node_modules\output-file-sync\index.js:45:3)
at write (D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:33:5)
at handleFile (D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:43:7)
at D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:61:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at handle (D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:59:29)
at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Web\\External\\Node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-pages" "--color=always"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! STS-VueApp@1.0.0 build-pages: `babel Scripts/Pages --out-dir Scripts/Compiled/Pages`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the STS-VueApp@1.0.0 build-pages script 'babel Scripts/Pages --out-dir Scripts/Compiled/Pages'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the STS-VueApp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel Scripts/Pages --out-dir Scripts/Compiled/Pages
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls STS-VueApp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\PasswordReset\Trunk\STS.PasswordReset.Web\npm-debug.log
Process terminated with code 1.
```

I thought maybe it was something having to do with the files not being included in my project, because I get a similar error from the component builds if my 'Scripts/Compiled' folder isn't included in the project, but including 'Scripts/Compiled/Pages' still gives me the same error and including the actual output file, ie: 'Scripts/Compiled/Pages/Index.js' doesn't fix it either.

Any ideas?? :\

Answer (score 1):

**It's only my thoughts.** But, can you please double check:

- do you run VS as Administrator?
- do you run Task Runner Explorer as Administrator?

Make sure that both works under Administrator.

Comment: Worked for me. Tried disabling anti-virus, running git bash as administrator, disabling winpty, etc. but only yours worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into something similar and the problem looks to be that babel is moving over the read only attrib on files that are under source control from VSS, i.e you pull a file from VSS it comes down with read only. The watch on it transpiles it to your target folder with read only on it. Subsequent transpiles fail as the target file won't get overwritten when it's set to read only.

I'm still working on the right solution to this but at the moment I have hacked up temp fix via a task runner command that removes read only on the entire target folder.

```
"babelJsxTranspileInit": "attrib -r [targetFolder]  /s",
```